# Installing CouchDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch on Windows

Tags: curl, installation, elasticsearch, couchdb

I have installed couchdb and elastic search and got them both up and running.

## First Issue

I am now trying to install the couchdb river plugin for elasticsearch.

per the directions here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb I open Windows 7 command-prompt and execute this:

```
bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/1.2.0
```

and i get this:

```
'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I know this must be simple...

## Second Issue

I also try to run the curl command to set the new index and i get this error (which i believe would happen regardless of the fact the plugin is not installed yet):

I have removed the single quotes because windows doesn't like them...

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/my_db/_meta -d {
    "type" : "couchdb",
    "couchdb" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "port" : 5984,
        "db" : "my_db",
        "filter" : null
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "my_db",
        "type" : "my_db",
        "bulk_size" : "100",
        "bulk_timeout" : "10ms"
    }
}
```

and i get this:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Un
expected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: [B@38ec57
4c; line: 1, column: 0])\n at [Source: [B@38ec574c; line: 1, column: 3]]; ","sta
tus":400}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: type                                 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                          
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"                        
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">                          
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">             
<head>                                                                          
<title>Method not allowed!</title>                                              
<link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />                          
<style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/                              
    body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; }                         
    a:link { color: #0000CC; }                                                  
    p, address {margin-left: 3em;}                                              
    span {font-size: smaller;}                                                  
/*]]>*/--></style>                                                              
</head>                                                                         
                                                                                
<body>                                                                          
<h1>Method not allowed!</h1>                                                    
<p>                                                                             
                                                                                
                                                                                
    The PUT                                                                     
    method is not allowed for the requested URL.                                
                                                                                
</p>                                                                            
<p>                                                                             
If you think this is a server error, please contact                             
the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.                        
                                                                                
</p>                                                                            
                                                                                
<h2>Error 405</h2>                                                              
<address>                                                                       
  <a href="/"></a><br />                                                        
  <span>Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.1</span>                    
</address>                                                                      
</body>                                                                         
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using this blog post

[Fulltext searching CouchDB with ElasticSearch](http://euphonious-intuition.com/2011/11/fulltext-searching-couchdb-with-elasticsearch/)

## Issue #1

I was not pointing to the correct 'plugin' file in the elasticsearch directory.

after navigating to '/bin' within my local elasticsearch directory and running this command i got it working:

```
plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/1.2.0
```

## Issue #2

I believe my cURL syntax was incorrect and didn't figure out what it was exactly but ended up using the [HttpRequester plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/). I believe its the double quotes that were causing problems.